# jQuery accordion Expand All

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I have several accordions in this format.

```
<div id="accordion-0" class="jquery-accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
<h3 class="some-class">Some other span elements here</h3></div>
```

In my page, I have a link that says *Expand All*, by clicking this link I want to be able to expand all my accordions.

```
<a href="javascript:expandAll(10);">
function expandAll(count) {
    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        $(function() {
            if ($("#accordion-" + i + " h3").attr("aria-selected") !== "true") {
                $("#accordion-" + i + " h3").click();

            }

        })
    }
}
```

Only the first accordion is getting expanded. I tried to put a `console.log()`  in the for loop to print the value of `i`, but it is printing only `0` which means my loop is getting terminated after the first expansion. I am unable to understand this behavior.

Any help is welcome. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".ui-accordion-content").show();
```

It will open all the accordion.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5hAw/1091/)

Comment: The fiddle is not working correctly as of 11/2022 as it will expand as intended when clicking "Expand All", but I noticed there is a mentioning of collapsing all and which is the part that is not working.

Comment: As an answer to @ryan: I tested on the browser console, and you can collapse all doing:
`$(".ui-accordion-content").hide();`

Comment: Yes, it does the trick but the visual state remains inconsistent : it should set "active" classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
 <a href="#" id="accordion-0">Expand All</a>
```

jquery:

```
  $(#).click(function(){
     $(".ui-accordion-content").show();
  });
```